# Copy selected text of a RichTextBox to the Clipboard with a Mouse Click

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox(RTB) that obtains text from two sources a txt file and data from a SQLite DB.
The RTB has `ReadOnly` property set to `False`.

I am trying to NOT use the ContextMenuStrip. This may be impossible ?
Here is the process fetch data from DB and populate the RTB
Highlight text I want to copy and click inside the RTB RESULT NO Copy

Second process tried same fetch data from DB this time I click on the form my code runs but no text is copied.
Here is the Code NOT neat but I am testing.

```
Public Class frmViewCode
Dim gvW As String

Public Sub rtbViewCode_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
    If e.Button = System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        BigCopy()
        MsgBox("It Worked")
    End If
End Sub
```

**OK I Changed BigCopy now the Selected code is added to the Clipboard**

But I still need to click on the Form to execute the code.
Still would like to click on the RTB to fire the BigCopy code ?

```
    Public Sub BigCopy()
    Dim start = rtbViewCode.SelectionStart
    Dim substring = rtbViewCode.Text.Substring(0, start)
    Dim words = substring.Split(New String() {" ", vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    Dim count = words.Length
    gvW = rtbViewCode.SelectedText
    Clipboard.SetText(gvW)
End Sub
```

I am curious as how to change the System.Windows.Forms so I can click on the RTB.
**The Question How to select text in a RTB and copy that text to the Clipboard with the Mouse?**

I also tried this code:

```
    Public Sub RightMouse_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim start = rtbViewCode.SelectionStart
    Dim substring = rtbViewCode.Text.Substring(0, start)
    Dim words = substring.Split(New String() {" ", vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    Dim count = words.Length
    MsgBox("Len " & count)
    lblMsg.Text = count.ToString()
    'gvW = words.ToString
    'gvW = rtbViewCode.SelectedText
    'Clipboard.SetText(gvW)

    Clipboard.SetText(rtbViewCode.SelectedRtf, TextDataFormat.Rtf)
    MsgBox("here " & gvW)
End Sub
```

Comment: The user SELECTS something in the RTB. Great. Now you want them to CLICK on the same RTB to copy? Wouldn't that just UNSELECT your current selection and put the insert cursor where the user clicked?! For the RichTextBox, set the `HideSelection` property to `false` and then add a BUTTON to the Form for the user to click on. Then you can fire your copy code from the Button instead.

Comment: @Idle_Mind The HideSelection change keeps the selected text highlighted and that is great. I agree the simplest solution is to add a Button to the Form. I have one Button that says Copy Code which use's rtbViewCode.SelectAll() So I'll just add another Button that says Copy Selected Code Thanks for your time and Answer

Comment: Use a `ContextMenuStrip` as usual. Then you can right-click on a selection and call the `Copy()` method (or `Paste()` or `Undo()` or `Redo()`...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd better off using a ContextMenuStrip. Anyway, you can use a Custom Control to trap `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and perform a copy when the Left Mouse Button is pressed, there's an active selection and the mouse Pointer is inside the selection.
In this case, you *suppress* the message, so the selection is not removed.

Set `HideSelection = False` if you want to keep the selection visible while moving the focus to other Controls.

If this is not exactly the intended behavior, change the `IsMouseDownInsideSelection()` method or the *logic* in `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`.

```
Public Class RichTextBoxEx
    Inherits RichTextBox

    Private Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &H201

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        If m.Msg = WM_LBUTTONDOWN Then
            If SelectionLength > 0 AndAlso IsMouseDownInsideSelection() Then
                Copy()
                Return
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub

    Private Function IsMouseDownInsideSelection() As Boolean
        Dim charIdx = GetCharIndexFromPosition(PointToClient(MousePosition))
        If charIdx >= SelectionStart AndAlso charIdx <= (SelectionStart + SelectionLength) Then Return True
        Return False
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks I need to explore custom controls a LOT more Great Answer If you see my Edit to the question the issue was a bunch of spaghetti code. Like you said I should have just went with the ContexMenuStrip

Comment: I hope it's of some use. Anyway, if you're interested in a ContextMenuStrip version of this, let me know, I'll post it.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use `Clipboard.SetText(RichTextBox1.Text)` Function To Copy All Text To Clipboard